# Clicks/touch not working on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have used ListView and bounded my custom ArrayAdapter to it.
Have setOnItemClickListener(...) bound to it.

Also have 2 buttons, 'next' and 'previous'. On click of each button I call a webservice and as per response received I update adapter( and expect ListView to get updated.)

My problem is that after few next and previous clicks, Touch does not works on ListView.

Have invested lot of time in figuring out, Please help me out.
one of my findings is: usually observed that problem occurs after GC.

Layout code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/layout1"
       style="@style/TitleBar"
       android:background="@drawable/top_bg" >
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/search_result_titleTxt"
           style="@style/TitleBarText"
           android:paddingLeft="8dip"
           android:text="@string/title_restaurants" />
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/sep"
           android:layout_width="1px"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
           android:background="@drawable/seprator_img" />
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/img1"
           style="@style/TitleBarLogo"
           android:background="@null"
           android:onClick="onMapClick"
           android:src="@drawable/map" />
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/filterSep"
           android:layout_width="1px"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
           android:background="@drawable/seprator_img" />
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/filter"
           style="@style/TitleBarLogo"
           android:background="@null"
           android:onClick="onSearchClick"
           android:src="@drawable/filter" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/background"
       android:padding="6dip" >
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/search_contentView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical" >
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/search_result_countTxt"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:focusable="false"
               android:text="@string/total_restaurants"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:visibility="gone" />
           <ListView
               android:id="@+id/search_result_list"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:background="@layout/customshape_table"
               android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
               android:divider="#BAC698"
               android:dividerHeight="2px"
               android:paddingLeft="4dip"
               android:paddingRight="4dip"
               android:scrollbars="none" />
           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/layout1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/search_result_prevBtn"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="left"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:background="@null"
                   android:onClick="onPrevBtnClick"
                   android:src="@drawable/previous_btn"
                   android:visibility="gone" />
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/search_result_nextBtn"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="right"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:background="@null"
                   android:gravity="right"
                   android:onClick="onNextBtnClick"
                   android:src="@drawable/next_btn"
                   android:visibility="gone" />
           </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   <HorizontalScrollView
       android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="55dip"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
       android:scrollbarSize="2dip"
       android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_thumb"
       android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_track" >
       <LinearLayout
        ...
       </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Adapter Code :

```
public class LazyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Resturant> {

private ArrayList<Resturant> resturants;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;

public LazyListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<Resturant> resturants) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, resturants);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.resturants = resturants;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    setNotifyOnChange(true);
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView restaurantName;
    public TextView address;
    public TextView completeAddress;
    public TextView cuisines;
    public ImageView image;
    ImageView offerImg;
    ImageView freqImg;
    TextView dinnerCountImg;
    ImageView friDashImg;
    ImageView friEveDashImg;
    ImageView satDashImg;
    ImageView satEveDashImg;
    ImageView sunDashImg;
    ImageView sunEveDashImg;
    ImageView callImg;
    TextView metricTxt;
    TextView distanceTxt;
    View overlay;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        System.out.println("pos:::::::::: " + position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                    vi = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.restaurantName = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_restTitleTxt);
        holder.address = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_addTxt);
        holder.completeAddress = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_complete_addTxt);
        holder.cuisines = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_cuisineTxt);
        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.search_item_image);
        holder.offerImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_specialOfferImg);
        holder.freqImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_frequencyImg);
        holder.dinnerCountImg = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_dinnerCountTxt);
        holder.friDashImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_friDashImg);
        holder.friEveDashImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_friDashEveImg);
        holder.satDashImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_satDashImg);
        holder.satEveDashImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_satDashEveImg);
        holder.sunDashImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_sunDashImg);
        holder.sunEveDashImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_sunDashEveImg);
        holder.callImg = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_callImg);
        holder.metricTxt = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_metricTxt);
        holder.distanceTxt = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_distanceTxt);
        holder.overlay = vi.findViewById(R.id.overlay);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    holder.restaurantName.setText(getCustomText(resturants.get(position)
            .getName()));
    holder.address.setText(getCustomText(resturants.get(position)
            .getAddress()));
    holder.completeAddress.setText(getCustomText(resturants.get(position)
            .getMergedAddress()));
    holder.cuisines.setText(Html.fromHtml(getCustomText("<b>Cuisine: </b>"
            + resturants.get(position).getCuisines())));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resturants.get(position).getImagePath(),
            holder.image);
    setAvalIcons(position, holder);
    getDistance(position, holder);

    if (resturants.get(position).getSpecialOffer() != null
            && !resturants.get(position).getSpecialOffer()
                    .equals(StringConstants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
        holder.overlay
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.specialoffers_strip);
        holder.overlay.invalidate();
    }
    return vi;
}

private void getDistance(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
    Setting setting = ((AppDelegate) ((Activity)context).getApplication())
            .getSetting();
    Resturant resturant = resturants.get(position);
    if (setting.getDistance() == 0) {
        holder.metricTxt.setText("miles");
        holder.distanceTxt.setText(resturant.getLocation());
    } else {
        holder.metricTxt.setText("kms");
        holder.distanceTxt.setText(resturant.getLocationInKm());
    }
}

public String getCustomText(String text) {
    if (text.length() > 30) {
        text = text.substring(0, 26);
        text = text + "...";
    }
    return text.toString();
}

public void reSet(ArrayList<Resturant> resturantsCache) {
    System.out.println("reSet(Resturant[] resturants) resturant :: "
            + resturantsCache.size());
    this.resturants = resturants;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setAvalIcons(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
    Resturant resturant = resturants.get(position);
    System.out.println("Special offer image Visibility :: "
            + resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(0));
    System.out.println("Special offer image  :: " + holder.offerImg);
    holder.offerImg.setVisibility(resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(0));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resturant.getOfferImage(), holder.offerImg);
    holder.freqImg.setVisibility(resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(1));
    if (resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(1) == View.VISIBLE) {
        holder.freqImg.setImageResource(resturant
                .getFrequencyImageDrawableId());
    }
    holder.dinnerCountImg.setVisibility(resturant
            .getSpecialIconsVisibility(2));
    holder.dinnerCountImg.setText(resturant.getDinersPerCard() + "D");
    holder.friDashImg.setVisibility(resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(3));
    holder.friEveDashImg.setVisibility(resturant
            .getSpecialIconsVisibility(4));
    holder.satDashImg.setVisibility(resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(5));
    holder.satEveDashImg.setVisibility(resturant
            .getSpecialIconsVisibility(6));
    holder.sunDashImg.setVisibility(resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(7));
    holder.sunEveDashImg.setVisibility(resturant
            .getSpecialIconsVisibility(8));
    holder.callImg.setVisibility(resturant.getSpecialIconsVisibility(9));
}

public void clearCache() {
    imageLoader.clearCache();
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    clearCache();
    super.clear();
}
}
```

List Class :

public abstract class SearchResultAbstractActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

```
protected LazyListAdapter adapter;
protected SearchResults searchResults;
protected SearchCriteria searchCriteria;
protected boolean isGuest = false;
protected ProgressDialog dialog;
protected String responseString;
protected boolean isNew = false;
protected boolean isFilter = false;
private View contentView;
protected static final String RETRIVE_RESTAURANTS = "RetriveRestaurants";
protected static final String DELETE_FAVOURITES = "DeleteFavourites";
protected static final String LOADING_MSG = "please wait\n\nloading restaurants...";
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            Bundle b = msg.getData();
            String action = b.getString(StringConstants.ACTION);
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(RETRIVE_RESTAURANTS)) {
                ...
                    ((AppDelegate) getApplication())
                            .setSearchResults(searchResults);
                    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
                    if (searchResults.getTotalCount() == 0) {
                        ...
                    } else {
                        if (adapter == null) {
                            adapter = new LazyListAdapter(SearchResultAbstractActivity.this, R.layout.search_item, 
                                    searchResults.getResturantList());
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } else {
                            if (list.getCount() > 0) {
                                list.setSelection(0);
                            }
                            adapter.reSet(searchResults.getResturantList());
                            list.refreshDrawableState();
                        }

                    }
                }
                ...
        }
        }
    };
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_result);

    Log.i("SearchResultActivity :: onStart() ",
            " ==========================I'm in start ============================");

    isNew = true;
    setTitle();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
    registerForContextMenu(list);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
        ...
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
    boolean isSet = setSearchCriteria();
    AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) getApplication();
    if (isSet && (isNew || isFilter || searchCriteria.isNew())) {
        if (adapter != null) {
            ImageView nextBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_nextBtn);
            ImageView prevBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_prevBtn);
            TextView countTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_countTxt);
            nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            prevBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            countTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter.clear();
            list.getEmptyView();
            searchResults.setPageNo(1);
            System.out
                    .println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Ohhhhhhh %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        }
        getFilteredResturants();
        isFilter = false;
        isNew = false;
        searchCriteria.setNew(false);
    }

    if (list.getOnItemClickListener() == null) {
        Log.e("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Started %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    ",
                "" + list.getOnItemClickListener());
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    System.out.println("Hi I'm signing offfffff..........");
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.clear();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent previewIntend = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            PreviewResturant.class);
    ...
    return true;
}

protected void setNextPrevVisibility() {
    ImageView nextBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_nextBtn);
    if (searchResults.isNext()) {
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    ImageView prevBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_prevBtn);
    if (searchResults.isPrev()) {
        prevBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        prevBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public void onPrevBtnClick(View v) {
    resetLastRestId();
    searchCriteria.setPrev(true);
    getFilteredResturants();
    searchResults.onPrev();
}

public void onNextBtnClick(View v) {
    resetLastRestId();
    searchCriteria.setPrev(false);
    getFilteredResturants();
    searchResults.onNext();
}

protected void resetLastRestId() {
    searchCriteria.setLastRestId(String.valueOf(searchResults.getResturant(
            searchResults.getResturantsCount() - 1).getId()));
}

protected void retriveResturants() {

    if (dialog == null || dialog.isShowing() == false) {

        if (((AppDelegate) getApplication())
                .isNetworkAvailable(SearchResultAbstractActivity.this)) {

            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> tempTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                ProgressDialog dialog;

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    Log.i("SearchActivity", "onPreExecute()");
                    dialog = MessageBox.showProgressDialog(
                            SearchResultAbstractActivity.this, dialog,
                            LOADING_MSG);
                    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            cancel(true);
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    try {
                        setSearchResult();
                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        ...
                        cancel(true);
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                        ...
                        cancel(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ...
                        cancel(true);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onCancelled() {
                    super.onCancelled();
                    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                    Log.i("SearchResultAbstractActivity", "onCancelled()");
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    Message message = new Message();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString(StringConstants.ACTION, RETRIVE_RESTAURANTS);
                    message.setData(b);
                    searchResults = JSONParser.parseResturants(
                            responseString, searchResults);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(message);
                    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            };
            tempTask.execute();

        } else {
            MessageBox.showAlert(SearchResultAbstractActivity.this,
                    StringConstants.CONNECTION_ERROR_TITLE,
                    StringConstants.CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("dialog.isShowing()  : dialog.isShowing() ",
                "dialog.isShowing()  " + dialog.isShowing());
    }

}

protected void setSearchResult() throws SoapFault, SocketException,
        Exception {
    responseString = getApiCallResponse();
}

protected String getApiCallResponse() throws SoapFault, SocketException,
        Exception {
    // try {
    return new SyncApiSoapCall(getApplicationContext(),
            StringConstants.URL_RESTAURANTS,
            StringConstants.METHOD_SEARCH_RESTAURANTS).callSearchApi(this,
            searchCriteria);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        ...
}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    ...
    super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);
}

private boolean getFilteredResturants() {
    MyLocationListener locationListener = ((AppDelegate) getApplication())
            .getLocationListener();
    Setting setting = ((AppDelegate) getApplication()).getSetting();
    boolean isValid = false;
    try {
        if ((setting.getGps() == 1 || searchCriteria.isNearMe())
                && searchCriteria.getIsLwp() == 0
                && searchCriteria.isFavourites() == false
                && (locationListener.getLatitude().equals(
                        StringConstants.DEFAULT_LAT_LONG) || locationListener
                        .getLongitude().equals(
                                StringConstants.DEFAULT_LAT_LONG))) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SearchResultAbstractActivity.this);

            builder.setMessage(StringConstants.MSG_LOCATION_ERROR)
                    .setTitle(StringConstants.MSG_TITLE_LOCATION_ERROR)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(StringConstants.MSG_OK_TEXT,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    retriveResturants();
                                }
                            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            isValid = true;
            retriveResturants();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // finish();
    }
    return isValid;
}

public void logout() {
...
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    Log.e("abstract search page :: Low Memory", " May kill me !!!!");
    super.onLowMemory();
}
protected abstract boolean setSearchCriteria();

protected abstract void setTitle();

protected abstract int getNoResultTitle();

// protected abstract String getNoResultMsg();
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your layout and java code so we can inspect

Comment: Post some code, otherwise no one will be able to help you on the basis of this post only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution : I was thinking that my list is not getting refreshed even if i fire  notifyDataSetChanged(); in public void reSet(ArrayList resturantsCache) of LazyListAdapter(Custom Adapter), but actually problem was with implementation of custom adapter.

I'm attaching my adapter code again, so that others can get solution.

Adapter :

```
package com.topnosh.campus.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.topnosh.campus.AppDelegate;
import com.topnosh.campus.R;
import com.topnosh.campus.constants.StringConstants;
import com.topnosh.campus.model.Resturant;
import com.topnosh.campus.model.Setting;

public class LazyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Resturant> {

public ImageLoader imageLoader;

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;

public LazyListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<Resturant> resturants) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, resturants);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    setNotifyOnChange(true);
}
...
public void reSet(ArrayList<Resturant> resturantsCache) {
    clear();
    for (Resturant resturant : resturantsCache) {
        add(resturant);
    }
}

...
}
```

Thanks to all those who noticed this issue and tried to help.